# brighter() method for Color class

Tags: java, colors

I've been trying out some easy java API's so I can get used to how the Java API is used. I'm still learning from it which is probably why I may be having this problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class ColorClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int r = 255, g = 255, b = 255;

        Color rgb = new Color(r, g, b);


        rgb.brighter();


        System.out.println("After Brighter: " + rgb.toString());


    }

}
```

Ouput

```
After Brighter: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
```

I want this output

```
After Brighter: java.awt.Color[r = 144, 144, 144]
```

Comment: There's no colour brighter than (255, 255, 255), it's definitely not (144, 144, 144)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `rgb.brighter();` returns a new `java.awt.Color` instance, you're ignoring this value and `rgb` still holds the original value
2. RGB(255, 255, 255) is the brightest color in the 24-bit pallette, the only brightness operation you can perform on it is `darker()`

A better test program would be:

```
public class ColorClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int r = 255, g = 255, b = 255;
        Color rgb = new Color(r, g, b);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rgb = rgb.darker();
            System.out.println("After darker(): " + rgb);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rgb = rgb.brighter();
            System.out.println("After brighter(): " + rgb);
        }
    }
}
```